# Not able to call method in diffrent class without write init method

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, init

I am not able to call `handleRegister` method on tap from another class.

I created a class named `A` which has `handleRegister` method:

```
class A {
   static var a:A?
   init(){
      A.a = self
   }

   @objc func handleRegister(){
      print("Hello method1")
   }
}
```

`ViewController` class from where i am calling `handleRegister` method:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  
    @IBOutlet weak private var btnFirst :UIButton?
  
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
       let obj = A()
       btnFirst?.addTarget(obj, action: #selector(obj.handleRegister), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    }
  
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

In my `ViewController` class i have `btnFirst` now i am trying to add target for `btnFirst` and try to calling `handleRegister` method which is form `class A` which is working fine.

> But my question is when i comment init method in class A then i m not able to call method `handleRegister`.
>
> can anyone tell me why `init` method important to add button target of another class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating `A` class object in `viewDidLoad` which will get deallocated immediately after the viewDidLoad. in `A` class initializer you are creating strong reference of A by writing this  `A.a = self` (that's why your button action is called). Simply create `A` class object outside `viewDidLoad` and it will work fine.